# Low disk space error in Android Studio on MAC during gradle sync and build

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, configuration, ide

I keep getting this error, almost twice or thrice every minute:

> Fatal Configuration Problem Low disk space in android studio system directory partition.

I have 300GB+ free on my hard-disk, how can I get rid of this?

Comment: What is your version of Android Studio ?

Comment: Android Studio, 
Version 1.2.1.1,
Build #AI-141.1903250  may05 Build,
JDK 1.8.0_45 x86_64,
JVM 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a related bug report : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118718

A workaround seems to be to add this property :

```
 idea.no.system.path.space.monitoring=true
```

in ~/Library/Preferences/<YOUR_ANDROID_STUDIO_VERSION>/studio.vmoptions